# alignSelf Does not make any change with layout "React native"

Tags: react-native, flexbox

JSX expression of the component as given below

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../images/background.jpg')} 
      style={styles.container}>        
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.viewStyleOne}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}> 1 </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.viewStyleTwo}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}> 2 </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.viewStyleThree}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}> 3 </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
</ImageBackground>
```

Style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center'
},
viewStyleTwo : {
    width:100,
    height:40,
    justifyContent : 'center',
    alignItems:'center', 
    backgroundColor: '#4DF25F'
},
viewStyleOne :{
    width:40,
    height:40,
    justifyContent : 'center',
    alignItems:'center', 
    backgroundColor: '#B54BF1',
    alignSelf : 'flex-start'
},
viewStyleThree:{
    width:40,
    height:40,
    justifyContent : 'center',
    alignItems:'center', 
    backgroundColor: '#F3B54E'
},
textStyle:{
    textAlign:'center'
}});
```

[image]

`viewStyleOne`  class contains a property `alignSelf` ,  But did not make any change, It should be at the top of the screen

The expected output should be as given in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Expected output should be first screenshot or second screenshot? :)

Comment: second screenshot @AndreiOlar

Comment: With the code provided, "1" is pushed to the top of the screen. Wasn't that the problem?

Comment: No, "1" is not pushed to the top of the screen with the Provided code. Now I am getting the following output https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIRsS.png
But I want like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZsyy.png

Comment: https://ibb.co/cymEhU
So that how it looks on my device with exactly the code you provided. Just instead of an `ImageBackground` I simply have a View, bu the exact same styling.

Comment: Yes But i am getting the output like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIRsS.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180930/discussion-between-andrei-olar-and-lalit-mohan).

Comment: Did you made any change in the code

Comment: No. Does the other answer work?

Comment: Yes height: "100%" works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following,

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        top: 0, 
        // Option 01
        height: "100%", // Added
        // OR  // Option 02
        // bottom: 0,
        // left: 0,
        // right : 0,
        // position: 'absolute',
        flexDirection:'row',
        alignItems:'center', 
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    viewStyleTwo : {
        width:40,
        height:40,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems:'center', 
        backgroundColor: '#4DF25F'
    },
    viewStyleOne :{
        width:40,
        height:40,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems:'center', 
        backgroundColor: '#B54BF1',
        alignSelf : 'flex-start'
    },
    viewStyleThree:{
        width:40,
        height:40,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems:'center', 
        backgroundColor: '#F3B54E'
    },
    textStyle:{
        textAlign:'center'
    }});
```

[Gives this UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lMKC.png)

Comment: Fix the Snippets or Remove it Please @Randika Swaris

Comment: Does my same code works for you @Randika Swaris, Or you also have same issue like i have

Comment: So what is the issue with my code I added the height: "100%" and it fixed and my same code works for other

Comment: @LalitMohan, I meant, the code snippet as it is. Adding height: "100%" to your code would do,